# How to add image picker with camera button to iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapture

I'm adding a button that opens a view of the saved images on device, but also has a button to open the camera. The iOS Facebook app currently does this.

I've played with both AVCapture to create my own camera ui and UIImagePickerController to use the default UI but have been unable to find a view that displays both the saved images and camera button.

My question is, did facebook implement their own image picker or is it an Apple included library?

Thanks!

Comment: The `UIImagePickerController` can show either the photo library or take a photo. The version for picking a photo from the library does not have any button for taking a photo. The other probably make their own image picker using `ALAssetsLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has their own imagepicker subclass but that doesnt matter for you - just implement a different method for each button that changes the imagepickertype to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` and then displays the picker.

Comment: Cool - that's what I figure I'll do.  I just wanted to see if Apple included an interface that would link to the photo library from their default camera.

Answer (score 0):

This came across this control [AQPhotoPicker](https://github.com/aqavi-paracha/AQPhotoPicker). Hopefully it will help you, it's easy to use